# The R code does not work on Linux terminal?

Tags: r, gbm

I have been running a code without any error, but recently, I am getting the error:

```
Error in (function (file = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else "Rplot%03d.pdf",  : 
  cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'
Calls: summary ... barplot -> barplot.default -> dev.hold -> <Anonymous>
```

Here is a part of the code:

```
      cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
      registerDoParallel(cl)
      set.seed(k)
      weighted_fit <- train(resp8mmrm ~ .
                            ,
                            data = train,
                            method = 'gbm',
                            trControl = ctrl)
      stopCluster(cl)
      rankgbm<-summary(weighted_fit)
```

I do not even have ggsave in my code, I just call the summary of a Gradient boosting algorithm and it opens up a plot automatically, I tried putting "pdf(NULL)", the code worked for a while but then stopped. This is really weird and giving me a hard time. Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Have you run out of disk space on the computer? Are the permissions for the current folder set badly? Failure to open a file is usually a bad sign and has less to do with your code and more with the system being messed up in some way.

Comment: Seems like a good point. This is a huge code that I am running it from pcloud drive which has free space.

Comment: Thank you so much @Konrad Rudolph. I really appreciate it. I changed the directory and the R code worked.